# Deleted all zmlinux's from /boot. Can't boot into anything now

Tags: boot, kernel, lenovo

I recently deleted all my vmlinux's in /boot for some reason (a bad misunderstanding between vmware and vmlinux...). Now I can't boot into any other OS's. For some reason I can boot into my Boot-repair DVD which I am using now on my lenovo G50. I was originally running ubuntu 14.04. I want to boot and install another OS but I can't for some reason.

Comment: is you rescue cd running on Linux?

Comment: You can't boot into any other OS's?  What happens if you try?  Did you delete `/boot/grub/` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Find your Ubuntu release number, codename. Boot from Live CD, download kernel package from your repository, unpack it and copy vmlinuz to /boot of your current installation. I will update answer if you need some description on each step.